# How to find if event source is created?

Tags: wix, event-log, eventlog-source

I am using the sample code to create event source:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <util:EventSource
      Name="Training Kiosk"
      Log="Application"
      EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll"
      />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

How do I confirm whether event source is created?

Answer (score 2):

EventSource creates rows in the Registry table; MSI reads those rows then writes them to the registry. So as long as the component is installed successfully, the event source will be "created"--because that's just a handful of registry entries.

Comment: To validate the event log exists post installation in your application, you can use the method EventLog.SourceExists(string Source)